# File Upload in laravel 8 - Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I have a Course Management CRUD.

The file Upload is giving me the following error

> Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

I am having this issue when i am updating the course without the attachment.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?
PS. I am new to Laravel & MVC frameworks.

Thanks in advance.

**Store & update method**

```
    public function CourseManagementStore(Request $request){
    $validatedData =$request->validate([
        'coursename' => 'required|unique:course_management',
        'file' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048',
        ]);

    $name = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('file')->store('public/uploads/coursedocs');
     

    $data = new CourseManagement();
    $data->coursename = $request->coursename;
    $data->courseshortname = $request->courseshortname;
    $data->awardingbody = $request->awardingbody;
    $data->coursecategory = $request->coursecategory;
    $data->courseduration = $request->courseduration;
    $data->issuedate = $request->issuedate;
    $data->validtill = $request->validtill;
    $data->molapprovaldate = $request->molapprovaldate;
    $data->molvalidtilldate = $request->molvalidtilldate;
    $data->feestrainingonly = $request->feestrainingonly;
    $data->feesexamonly = $request->feesexamonly;
    $data->feesindividual = $request->feesindividual;
    $data->feestamkeen = $request->feestamkeen;
    $data->feesmol = $request->feesmol;
    $data->feescompanysponsor = $request->feescompanysponsor;
    $data->courseref = $request->courseref;
    $data->molref = $request->molref;
    $data->courseregstatus = $request->courseregstatus;
    $data->coursedescription = $request->coursedescription;
    $data->coursedocdesc = $request->coursedocdesc;
    $data->trainer = $request->trainer;
    $data->name = $name;
    $data->path = $path;
    $data->save();

    $notification = array (
        'message' => 'Course Added successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('course.viewall')->with($notification);
}    


public function CourseManagementUpdate(Request $request, $id){
    $data = CourseManagement::find($id);

    $name = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('file')->store('public/uploads/coursedocs');


    $data = new CourseManagement();
    $data->coursename = $request->coursename;
    $data->courseshortname = $request->courseshortname;
    $data->awardingbody = $request->awardingbody;
    $data->coursecategory = $request->coursecategory;
    $data->courseduration = $request->courseduration;
    $data->issuedate = $request->issuedate;
    $data->validtill = $request->validtill;
    $data->molapprovaldate = $request->molapprovaldate;
    $data->molvalidtilldate = $request->molvalidtilldate;
    $data->feestrainingonly = $request->feestrainingonly;
    $data->feesexamonly = $request->feesexamonly;
    $data->feesindividual = $request->feesindividual;
    $data->feestamkeen = $request->feestamkeen;
    $data->feesmol = $request->feesmol;
    $data->feescompanysponsor = $request->feescompanysponsor;
    $data->courseref = $request->courseref;
    $data->molref = $request->molref;
    $data->courseregstatus = $request->courseregstatus;
    $data->coursedescription = $request->coursedescription;
    $data->coursedocdesc = $request->coursedocdesc;
    $data->trainer = $request->trainer;
    $data->name = $name;
    $data->path = $path;
    $data->save();





    $notification = array (
        'message' => 'Course updated successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('course.viewall')->with($notification);
}
```

**Update Course Form**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('course.update', $editData->id ) }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="upload-file">
    @csrf
<!-- Basic Forms -->
<!-- .box-header -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Edit Course</h4>
    </div>
<!-- /.box-header -->

<!-- .box-body -->
<div class="box-body">
<div class="row"><!-- .box-body row-->
<div class="col"><!-- .box-body col-->

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">            
                    
                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Course Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="coursename"  class="form-control" value="{{ $editData ->coursename }}" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                </div>
                                    @error('coursename')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Course Short Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="courseshortname" value="{{ $editData ->courseshortname }}"  class="form-control" >
                                </div>
                                    @error('courseshortname')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                    </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
                </div><!-- end row -->


                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Awarding Body <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <select name="awardingbody" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                <option value="{{ $editData->awardingbody }}">{{ $editData->awardingbody }}</option>
                                    @foreach($awardingbodies as $awardingbody)
                                    <option>{{$awardingbody->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Course Category <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <select name="coursecategory" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                <option value="{{ $editData->coursecategory }}">{{ $editData->coursecategory }}</option>
                                    @foreach($coursecategories as $coursecategory)
                                    <option>{{$coursecategory->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
                </div><!-- end row -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-3"> <!-- start col 3 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Course Ref Number<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="courseref" value="{{ $editData ->courseref }}" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                </div>
                                    @error('courseref')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>MOL Ref Number<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="molref"  value="{{ $editData ->molref }}" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                </div>
                                    @error('molref')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 3 -->

                    <div class="col-md-3"> <!-- start col 3 -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Trainer<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="trainer"  value="{{ $editData ->trainer }}"  class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                </div>
                                    @error('trainer')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Course Duration<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="courseduration"  value="{{ $editData ->courseduration }}"  class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                </div>
                                    @error('courseduration')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 6 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Course Description <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="coursedescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Textarea">  {{ $editData ->coursedescription }}</textarea>
                                </div>
                                    @error('coursedescription')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 6 -->
               </div><!-- end row -->


        </div> <!-- end col-->
        </div><!-- end row -->

</div><!--/ .box-body col-->
</div><!--/ .box-body row-->
</div><!--/ .box-body -->
</div> <!--/ .box -->



<div class="box"> <!-- .box -->
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Fees</h4>
    </div>

<div class="box-body"><!-- .box-body -->
<div class="row"> <!-- .box-body row -->
<div class="col"> <!-- .box-body col -->
        <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->

            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- start col 2 -->
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Training Only<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="feestrainingonly"  value="{{ $editData ->feestrainingonly }}"   class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                        </div>
                            @error('feestrainingonly')
                            <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                </div>
            </div><!-- end col 2 -->

            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- start col 2 -->
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Exam Only<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="feesexamonly"  value="{{ $editData ->feesexamonly }}"   class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                        </div>
                            @error('feesexamonly')
                            <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                </div>
            </div><!-- end col 2 -->

            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- start col 2 -->
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Individual Fees<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="feesindividual"  value="{{ $editData ->feesindividual }}"   class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                        </div>
                            @error('feesindividual')
                            <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                </div>
            </div><!-- end col 2 -->

            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- start col 2 -->
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Tamkeen Fees<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="feestamkeen"  value="{{ $editData ->feestamkeen }}"   class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                        </div>
                            @error('feestamkeen')
                            <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                </div>
            </div><!-- end col 2 -->

            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- start col 2 -->
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>MOL Fees<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="feesmol"  value="{{ $editData ->feesmol }}"   class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                        </div>
                            @error('feesmol')
                            <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                </div>
            </div><!-- end col 2 -->

            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- start col 2 -->
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Company Sponsor Fees<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="feescompanysponsor"  value="{{ $editData ->feescompanysponsor }}"  class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                        </div>
                            @error('feescompanysponsor')
                            <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                </div>
            </div><!-- end col 2 -->
            
        </div><!-- end row -->


</div><!--/ .box-body col-->
</div><!--/ .box-body row-->
</div><!--/ .box-body -->
</div> <!--/ .box -->



<div class="box"> <!-- .box -->
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Issue & Validation Dates</h4>
    </div>
<div class="box-body"><!-- .box-body -->
<div class="row"> <!-- .box-body row -->
<div class="col"> <!-- .box-body col -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>MOL Approval Issue Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="date" name="molapprovaldate"  value="{{ $editData ->molapprovaldate }}" class="form-control" >
                                </div>
                                    @error('molapprovaldate')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>MOL Approval Valid Till <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="date" name="molvalidtilldate"  value="{{ $editData ->molvalidtilldate }}" class="form-control" >
                                </div>
                                    @error('molvalidtilldate')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
                </div><!-- end row -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Issue Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="date" name="issuedate"  class="form-control"  value="{{ $editData ->issuedate }}" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                </div>
                                    @error('issuedate')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Valid Till <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="date" name="validtill"  value="{{ $editData ->validtill }}"  class="form-control" >
                                </div>
                                    @error('validtill')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
                </div><!-- end row -->

</div><!--/ .box-body col-->
</div><!--/ .box-body row-->
</div><!--/ .box-body -->
</div> <!--/ .box -->



<div class="box"> <!-- .box -->
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Documents</h4>
    </div>
<div class="box-body"><!-- .box-body -->
<div class="row"> <!-- .box-body row -->
<div class="col"> <!-- .box-body col -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Document Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  class="form-control" >
                                </div>
                                    @error('Course Document')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <h5>Description <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea rows="3" cols="5" name="coursedocdesc" class="form-control" placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
                </div><!-- end row -->


</div><!--/ .box-body col-->
</div><!--/ .box-body row-->
</div><!--/ .box-body -->
</div> <!--/ .box -->


<div class="box"> <!-- .box -->
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Course Status</h4>
    </div>
<div class="box-body"><!-- .box-body -->
<div class="row"> <!-- .box-body row -->
<div class="col"> <!-- .box-body col -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
                    <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- start col 12 -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h5>Course Registration Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select name="courseregstatus"  id="select" required class="form-control">
                                    <option value="{{ $editData ->courseregstatus }}">{{ $editData ->courseregstatus }}</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Valid">Valid</option>
                                    <option value="Expired">Expired</option>
                                    <option value="Processing-Renewal">Processing Renewal</option>
                                    <option value="Course-Khallas">Course Khallas!</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- start col 12 -->
                </div><!-- end row -->

</div><!--/ .box-body col-->
</div><!--/ .box-body row-->
</div><!--/ .box-body -->
</div> <!--/ .box -->
        <div class="text-xs-right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded mb-5" value="Update">
        </div>
        
    </form>
```

Comment: $name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file->store('public/uploads/coursedocs');  try without the file() function.

Comment: @Cameron nope. Getting the same error with that.

Answer (score 2):

As adding the file is not mandatory, you must test your `$request->file('file')` if it's **null or not**. So add this to your code to avoid the error :

```
public function CourseManagementUpdate(Request $request, $id){

    $data = CourseManagement::find($id);
    $data->coursename = $request->coursename;
    $data->courseshortname = $request->courseshortname;
    $data->awardingbody = $request->awardingbody;
    $data->coursecategory = $request->coursecategory;
    $data->courseduration = $request->courseduration;
    $data->issuedate = $request->issuedate;
    $data->validtill = $request->validtill;
    $data->molapprovaldate = $request->molapprovaldate;
    $data->molvalidtilldate = $request->molvalidtilldate;
    $data->feestrainingonly = $request->feestrainingonly;
    $data->feesexamonly = $request->feesexamonly;
    $data->feesindividual = $request->feesindividual;
    $data->feestamkeen = $request->feestamkeen;
    $data->feesmol = $request->feesmol;
    $data->feescompanysponsor = $request->feescompanysponsor;
    $data->courseref = $request->courseref;
    $data->molref = $request->molref;
    $data->courseregstatus = $request->courseregstatus;
    $data->coursedescription = $request->coursedescription;
    $data->coursedocdesc = $request->coursedocdesc;
    $data->trainer = $request->trainer;

    if ( isset($request->file('file')) != null ) {
         $data->name = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
         $data->path = $request->file('file')->store('public/uploads/coursedocs');
    }
    
    $data->save();



    $notification = array (
        'message' => 'Course updated successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('course.viewall')->with($notification);
}
```

Comment: And it looks like `$data = new CourseManagement();` is not meant to be there. You actually already assigned $data via the find and then you completly overwrite it (just to enhance this answer)

Comment: @Frnak I corrected that, thank you

Comment: @atika i am getting the below errow now, when i load the view

` 
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
`

Comment: @Frnak Any help guys?

Comment: Try to change by `if( isset($request->file('file')) )`

Comment: @Atika Nope.. same error

Comment: try `if ( null != $request->file('file') )` - isset won't work here

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the optional() helper

```
$name = optional($request->file('file'))->getClientOriginalName();  
$path = optional($request->file('file'))->store('public/uploads/coursedocs');
```

it returns null and doesn't error if the object doesn't exist.
info here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional

Comment: I just notified this helper function today.  thanks.